# Working with Collectionview inside UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I Have yet to find a solution for this issue. I have attached a video to my app to see it in action.

The problem is posted at the bottom of whats occurring and what should be occurring.

https://www.mediacloud.cc/a/public/85156c9d4867ec82a42002e21954ee70.php?lang=en

I am using singleton method to pass data between my two View Controllers because they aren't directly connected.

The 4 relevant classes I am working with are, MyAppDelegate, CameraViewController, TableViewController, and CaptureSession.

**My appDelegate.h class**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *emailProperty;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imageProperty;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryProperty;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *emailStringProperty;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *assetImageProperty;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *captureImageProperty;

+ (id)sharedManager;
```

**My appDelegate.m Class**

```
@synthesize emailProperty;

@synthesize imageProperty;

@synthesize dictionaryProperty;

@synthesize emailStringProperty;

@synthesize assetImageProperty;

@synthesize captureImageProperty;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedManager {

static MediaCloudAppDelegate *sharedMyManager = nil;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
});
return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {

    emailProperty = [NSMutableArray array];

    imageProperty = [NSMutableArray array];

    dictionaryProperty = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

}
return self;
}
```

**CameraViewController.m Class**

When a user is in the CameraViewController, He presses "take a photo" right after the the touch event a UIalertview pops up to ask him to enter his email. 
this is the code for handling user input.

```
_emailString1 = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;


        MediaCloudAppDelegate *sharedManager = [MediaCloudAppDelegate sharedManager];

        sharedManager.emailStringProperty = _emailString1;

        [sharedManager.emailProperty addObject:sharedManager.emailStringProperty];
```

After the user enters their email and clicks ok they can now take a photo.

Since I am using AVCapturesSession to take the photo. This is the code.

**CaptureSession.m Class**

```
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput 
jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

[self setStillImage:image];


MediaCloudAppDelegate *sharedManager = [MediaCloudAppDelegate sharedManager];


sharedManager.captureImageProperty = image;


[sharedManager.dictionaryProperty setObject:sharedManager.captureImageProperty 
          forKey:sharedManager.emailStringProperty];


[sharedManager.imageProperty addObject:sharedManager.dictionaryProperty];

NSLog(@"image %@", sharedManager.imageProperty);
```

after the photo is taken I log the output.

For example. Lets say a user email is bob@email.com and takes a photo of himself.

My NSLog(@"image %@", sharedManager.imageProperty); is image

```
    {
    bob@email.com = "UIImage: 0x1568d8c0";
    }
```

Now to show all the photos and emails that the app has taken we go to the TableViewController.

**TableViewController.m Class**

My table view design is like so. In a cell I have a UICollectionView and to the right I have a UILabel.

I display the array of emails like so.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

MediaCloudAppDelegate *sharedManager = [MediaCloudAppDelegate sharedManager];
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return  sharedManager.emailProperty.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

EmailViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier

 forIndexPath:indexPath];


MediaCloudAppDelegate *sharedManager = [MediaCloudAppDelegate sharedManager];


cell.emailLabel.text = [sharedManager.emailProperty objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;
}
```

And to display the photos in the collection view thats inside the cell I do this.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  
cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier
forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    MediaCloudAppDelegate *sharedManager = [MediaCloudAppDelegate sharedManager];



sharedManager.dictionaryProperty = [sharedManager.imageProperty objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

imageView.image = [sharedManager.dictionaryProperty 
objectForKey:sharedManager.emailStringProperty];


return cell;


}
```

And now everything works the only problem is each collection view in each cell displays the entire array of photos not the photos that are associated with the unique email string.

So if I had there rows.

Row 1 is Bob
Row 2 is Jeff
Row 3 is Dave

And we had a photo of each person. The Collection View in Bob's row should only show a picture of Bob. And the Collection view in Jeff's row should only show a picture of Jeff and so on. 
The problem right now is. Collection View in Bob's row show photos of all three people and same goes for the other two.

And I have no Idea how to make it work.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a collection view to show only one item?  (BTW in your cellForItemAtIndexPath, you should call indexPath.item instead of indexPath.row)

Comment: So the app will work with single images, as well as multiple images. So a user could select 5 photos from the camera roll click "done" and then enter their email. Go to table view and those 5 photos would be in the cell his email is. But I just chose to show single images as an example.

Comment: What does your number of items in section return for your collection view?

Comment: @AMayes this is how I have it.                                              - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    MediaCloudAppDelegate *sharedManager = [MediaCloudAppDelegate sharedManager];
    return sharedManager.imageProperty.count;
}

Answer (score 1):

You should store the images you want displayed in each tableView cell as an array, then pass that array to an individual collectionView instance.  You can't just use one array to store all images and expect the various collectionViews to pick and choose which images to display.  (Well, you can, but it's a LOT harder)

The way you pass the information in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will depend on how your custom Cell object is organized.

One way to do this would be to store each array in a dictionary, keyed by user email.  Another would be to store all your arrays in another master array, indexed by indexPath.row.

If this is unclear, let me know.  So when you capture the image, add it to an array and store it in an array, which you then add to your dictionary:

```
sharedManager.captureImageProperty = image;

NSMutableArray *array = sharedManager.dictionaryProperty[sharedManager.emailStringProperty];
if (!array) array = [NSMutableArray new];
[array addObject: sharedManager.captureImageProperty];

[sharedManager.dictionaryProperty setObject:array 
          forKey:sharedManager.emailStringProperty];
```

Then grab the array out of the dictionary and pass it to your collectionView for each cell.

In your collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath, implement the following:

```
sharedManager.dictionaryProperty = [sharedManager.imageProperty objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
```

// New

```
NSArray *array = [sharedManager.dictionaryProperty objectForKey:sharedManager.emailStringProperty];
imageView.image = array[indexPath.item];
```

Comment: AMayes, So I am understanding the gist of it. I would have an array of arrays which holds the photos. But I am not sure how to go about actually doing it. Especially the part of creating a new array for every email. Could you expand on that? Thanks.

Comment: AMayes, This is very noob of me I apologize. I tried searching for how I can properly grab the array out of the dictionary. And I can't find nothing. All the cases that I'm finding show an NSarray that contains multiple dictionaries not other way. Couple of things I tried and these don't work. 1. imageView.image = [[sharedManager.dictionaryProperty objectForKey:sharedManager.emailStringProperty]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 2.  NSArray *array = [sharedManager.dictionaryProperty objectForKey:sharedManager.emailStringProperty];
 imageView.image = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: #2 should work.  But it depends on how your sharedManager is set up.

Comment: In my TableViewController in view did load. I NSLog the array like so. NSArray *array = [sharedManager.dictionaryProperty objectForKey:sharedManager.emailStringProperty];
  NSLog(@"array photos %@", array); And it prints out all the images I have but for some reason still not working in the collection view. CORRECTION its only printing out 1 UIImage not all in the array.

Comment: I thought you only put 1 image in the array for each email.  In that case, it would be logging correctly.

Comment: My bad that is correct. I also logged sharedManager.dictionaryProperty allKeys. And that printed out all the images. But still displaying them in a collection view they don't show up. Even though the array is not nil. I am just lost.

Comment: A couple of things if I delete sharedManager.dictionaryProperty = [sharedManager.imageProperty objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]; The collection view shows 1 photo. But as soon as I add another photo and go back to the tableview the app crashes and I get this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]. And what exactly do I put in CollectionView numberOfItemsInSection: I currently have NSArray *array = [sharedManager.dictionaryProperty allValues];
    
    return  array.count;